# create a folder out of working folder without use of double period with Dir.mkdir

Tags: ruby, directory, parent, working-directory, sanitizer

Is it possible to create a folder outside of working folder without direct use of double period with ruby's `Dir.mkdir s` or `mkdir_p s`. I am interested in linux-like systems only.

My goal it to sanitise a user provided folder name, I plan to keep single stops for 'name extension purposes'

Tildes and control characters are also removed.

Note that I am aware that it is possible to merely compare normalised names of working folders and user suggested, yet I am more interested in performing silent sanitation by dropping/replacing unsafe elements rather than producing an error message.

Comment: Do you mean [`expand_path`](https://rubyapi.org/3.2/o/file#method-c-expand_path) which resolves `..` and `~`?

Comment: It might be easier to restrict the folder name to _safe_ characters, for example only allow (ASCII) letters, digits, hyphen and underscore.

Comment: Stefan, it is more or less what I do. I though  allow slashes and single periods, spaces. The use case for single period is folder name extensions, some users like those.

I am still curious what minimal/meanigful restriction could be

Comment: @Serge different file systems and operating systems have different restrictions regarding special / reserved characters and also limitations regarding character range (Unicode). https://stackoverflow.com/q/1976007/477037 might help (contains many links to external resources).